# Does indexing an array w/ arithmetic rather than an explicit/single value, cause issues?

Tags: c, arrays, operator-precedence

```
a[b]
```

Is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, so...

```
a[b & c]
```

Where `&` has a lower operator precedence than `+`, would this result in `*(a + b & c)` or `*(a + (b & c))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**C Standard, § 6.5.2.1**, *Array Subscripting*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) says:

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

Note the brackets surrounding `E2`. The latter expression (`*(a + (b & c))`) is the correct outcome.

Answer (score 2):

`a[b]` is `*((a) +(b))` so `a[b & c]` is `*((a)+(b & c))` being `*(a+(b & c))` if you prefer